# Most frequent character in Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, count, range, character

This program lets the user enter a string and displays the character that appears most frequently in a string.
I need help explaining **frequent = i**.

```
# This program displays the character that appears most frequently in the string

def main():

    # Local variables.
    count = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    index = 0
    frequent = 0

    # Get input.
    user_string = input('Enter a string: ')
    for ch in user_string:
        ch = ch.upper()

        # Determine which letter this character is.
        index = letters.find(ch)
        if index >= 0:

            # Increase counting array for this letter.
            count[index] = count[index] + 1

    # Please help me explain this entire part!
    for i in range(len(count)):
        if count[i] > count[frequent]:
            frequent = i

    print('The character that appears most frequently' \
          ' in the string is ', letters[frequent], '.', \
          sep='')


# Call main
main()
```

Comment: `frequent = i` remembers the index of the highest count seen in the `count` list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet in question:

```
for i in range(len(count)):
    if count[i] > count[frequent]:
        frequent = i
```

First the for loop iterates over the length of count which is 26.

The if statement:

```
if count[i] > count[frequent]:
```

Checks to see if the current letter in the for loop is larger than the current most frequent character. If it is then it sets the new most frequent character as the index of the for loop.

For example,

If A is referenced 12 times and B is referenced 14 then on the second loop when i = 1 the if statement would look like this:

```
if 12 > 14:
   frequent = 1
```

This sets frequent to 1 which can be used to find the frequency in count for ex.
count[1] == 14

Answer (score 0):

There are 26 different items in the list `count`, and 26 letters in the charset. It iterates through the `count` list for each item (that's the `for i in range (len(count))` part) and then sees if the value of that item is greater than the value of the current largest item it's found - simply speaking it finds the largest value in the array, but instead of getting the value it gets the index, `frequent = i` is setting the index of the largest value currently found as it iterates to the variable `frequent`. It's simpler and more pythonistic to simply do 
    frequent = index(max(count)
which has EXACTLY the same effect